# How to load data in info window from database in google map using ajax in asp.net mvc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to load multiple markers with info window including data from database. problem is that it doesn't show any data from `db`, but showing markers with empty info window.

> **controller**

```
public JsonResult GetAllLocation()
        {
            var data = db.tb_freeslot.ToList();
            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

> **view**

```
<div id="map"></div>
        <script>
         var map;
         function initMap(zoomeLevel, latDb, longDb) {
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: { lat: latDb != null ? latDb : 10.523900, lng: longDb != null ? longDb : 76.212250 },
              zoom: zoomeLevel != null ? zoomeLevel : 15
          });
      }
      $.ajax({
          url: '/user/GetAllLocation',
          type: 'GET',
          success: function (data) {
                                var markers = [];
                                    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                                      var marker = {};
                                           marker["title"] = item.slotinfree_name;
                  marker["lat"] = item.Lat_infree;
                  marker["lng"] = item.Long_infree;
                  marker["description"] = item.car_freeslot;
                  markers.push(marker);
              })
                                  initializeMap(markers);}});
         var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), GoogleMapOptions);
                         for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
              var data = markers[i]
                              var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
                  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: myLatlng,
                  map: map,
                  title: data.title
              });
                  (function (marker, data) {
                  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                      infoWindow.setContent(data.title);
                      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                  });
              })(marker, data);}}
    </script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBNKM7UFRBfd6BfD3UwfRQRRpSgu2TsiU&callback=initmap"
            async="" defer="defer" ></script>
```

Comment: solved this issue by `list` that corresponding table's data and retrieve that required data on `mouseover` event by using `this` operator.